# I have a issue With Jquery Tab Menu

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I'm Using Jquery Tab Menu is working very well if i'm using inline tab option. but when i call remote file i getting issue. remote file containing HTML form. I have 3 Tab 2 tabs are static 3 tab is call via remote file. when i write any thing in 3 tab menu field is okay but when i change tab and again come in 3 tab all values are clear.

```
$(function() 
{
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
          ui.panel.html(
            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
            "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
        });
      }
    });
});


$(function()
{
    $('#readymadesizes').click(function () 
    {      
          var isChecked = $('#readymadesizes').prop('checked');
          if(isChecked)
          {
                $("div#tabs ul").append("<li><a id='autotab' href='http://arwebdesigners.info/test/form.php'>Product Options</a></li>");
                $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");

                $("#standardstitching").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#customtailoring").prop("disabled", true);
          }
          else
          {
             $('div#tabs #autotab').remove();
             $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");

             $("#standardstitching").prop("disabled", false);
             $("#customtailoring").prop("disabled", false);
          }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Product Description</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs-1">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="admintext tableboder">
         <tr>
           <td height="10" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td width="20%"><strong>Product Name:</strong></td>
           <td colspan="2"><input name="productname" type="text"  id="productname"  /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>Price</strong></td>
           <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="mainprice" name="mainprice"  ></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>SKU:</strong></td>
           <td colspan="2"><input name="sku" type="text" id="sku"   /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
           <td><strong>Image:</strong></td>
           <td colspan="2"><input name="productimage" type="file"  id="productimage"  style="width:215px;"  /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>Discount:</strong></td>
           <td width="23%"><input name="discount" type="text"  id="discount" /></td>
           <td width="57%"><select name="discountmode" id="discountmode" class="input short">
             <option value="$" >$</option>
             <option value="%" >%</option>
           </select></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>Ready Made Sizes:</strong></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="readymadesizes" name="readymadesizes" value="readymadesizes" ></td>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>Standard  Stitching Option:</strong></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="standardstitching" name="standardstitching" value="standardstitching" ></td>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>Custom Tailoring:</strong></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="customtailoring" name="customtailoring" value="customtailoring"  ></td>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>Special:</strong></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="special" name="special" value="Special" ></td>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>Bestseller:</strong></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="bestseller" name="bestseller" value="bestseller" ></td>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>Clearance:</strong></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="clearance" name="clearance" value="clearance" ></td>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>New Arrival:</strong></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="newarrival" name="newarrival" value="newarrival" ></td>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
        </table>
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-2">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="admintext tableboder">
         <tr>
           <td height="10" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td width="35%"><strong>Description:</strong></td>
           <td width="130%" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td colspan="3"><?php

            $initialValue = $id > '0' ? stripslashes($row['proddes']) : '';
            $sBasePath = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
            $sBasePath="../CKEditor/";
            //print_r($sBasePath); exit;
            $CKEditor = new CKEditor();
            $CKEditor->config['filebrowserBrowseUrl'] = '../CKEditor/filemanagers/index.html';
            $CKEditor->basePath = $sBasePath;
            $CKEditor->config['toolbar'] = 'Full';
            $CKEditor->config['uiColor'] = EDITOR_COLOR;
            $CKEditor->config['height'] = 250;
            $CKEditor->config['resize_enabled'] = false;

            $CKEditor->editor("pagecontent", $initialValue);
         ?></td>
           </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() 
{
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
          ui.panel.html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " + "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
        });
      }
    });
});


$(function()
{
    $('#readymadesizes').click(function () 
    {      
          var isChecked = $('#readymadesizes').prop('checked');
          if(isChecked)
          {
                $("div#tabs ul").append("<li><a id='autotab' href='http://arwebdesigners.info/test/form.php'>Product Options</a></li>");
                $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");

                $("#standardstitching").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#customtailoring").prop("disabled", true);
          }
          else
          {
             $('div#tabs #autotab').remove();
             $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");

             $("#standardstitching").prop("disabled", false);
             $("#customtailoring").prop("disabled", false);
          }
    });
});
</script>
```

Please Add '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>'

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Product Description</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs-1">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="admintext tableboder">
         <tr>
           <td height="10" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td width="20%"><strong>Product Name:</strong></td>
           <td colspan="2"><input name="productname" type="text"  id="productname"  /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>Price</strong></td>
           <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="mainprice" name="mainprice"  ></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>SKU:</strong></td>
           <td colspan="2"><input name="sku" type="text" id="sku"   /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
           <td><strong>Image:</strong></td>
           <td colspan="2"><input name="productimage" type="file"  id="productimage"  style="width:215px;"  /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>Discount:</strong></td>
           <td width="23%"><input name="discount" type="text"  id="discount" /></td>
           <td width="57%"><select name="discountmode" id="discountmode" class="input short">
             <option value="$" >$</option>
             <option value="%" >%</option>
           </select></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>Ready Made Sizes:</strong></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="readymadesizes" name="readymadesizes" value="readymadesizes" ></td>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>Standard  Stitching Option:</strong></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="standardstitching" name="standardstitching" value="standardstitching" ></td>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>Custom Tailoring:</strong></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="customtailoring" name="customtailoring" value="customtailoring"  ></td>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>Special:</strong></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="special" name="special" value="Special" ></td>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>Bestseller:</strong></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="bestseller" name="bestseller" value="bestseller" ></td>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>Clearance:</strong></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="clearance" name="clearance" value="clearance" ></td>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>New Arrival:</strong></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="newarrival" name="newarrival" value="newarrival" ></td>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
        </table>
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-2">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="admintext tableboder">
         <tr>
           <td height="10" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td width="35%"><strong>Description:</strong></td>
           <td width="130%" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td colspan="3"><?php

            $initialValue = $id > '0' ? stripslashes($row['proddes']) : '';
            $sBasePath = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
            $sBasePath="../CKEditor/";
            //print_r($sBasePath); exit;
            $CKEditor = new CKEditor();
            $CKEditor->config['filebrowserBrowseUrl'] = '../CKEditor/filemanagers/index.html';
            $CKEditor->basePath = $sBasePath;
            $CKEditor->config['toolbar'] = 'Full';
            $CKEditor->config['uiColor'] = EDITOR_COLOR;
            $CKEditor->config['height'] = 250;
            $CKEditor->config['resize_enabled'] = false;

            $CKEditor->editor("pagecontent", $initialValue);
         ?></td>
           </tr>
         <tr>
           <td height="8" colspan="3"></td>
         </tr>
         </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/anujsoft/xdcxfh86/